# how to configure machine settings for all users for IE windows server 2008 IE 9?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, internet-explorer-9

I have code that should make a screenshot from IE WebBrowser control so when I set the IE settings for from the security tab in internet options it seems to be separated per each user.

So I decided to use Edit group policy and setting the option use only machine settings to Enabled but the problem is all the security options is overridden by the machine settings for IE so I found that modifying the following registry path:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings will fix the problem
but the major problem that this key doesn't exists so I'm totally lost
anyone can tell me how to modify the IE 9 Maching settings on Windows server RC2

Comment: it solved here   http://serverfault.com/questions/76351/how-to-automatically-set-ie-settings-for-all-users